# JQuery Image Slider on MouseEnter

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am having issues having my images rotate back to the first image on mouseleave and resetting the active. It works without mouse events, but I need it to only go through images on hover and reset when someone leaves the div area. When I added the mouseleave event it will stop but will not reset properly and still go through the images.

```js
var cur = 0;
var count = $('.slider_item').length;

$('.slider_item').hide();
$('.slider_item').eq(0).show();
$('.image-container').mouseenter( function() {
setInterval(function() {    
    $('.slider_item').eq(cur).slideToggle(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        cur = (cur + 1) % count;
        $('.slider_item').eq(cur).addClass('active').slideToggle('slow');
 });
}, 5000);
$('.image-container').mouseleave( function() {
   $('.slider_item').removeClass('active');
   $('.slider_item').eq(0).show();
   
  });

});
});
```

```css
.image-container {
width:84px;
height:115px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;}


.image-container img {
     position:relative;
}
```

```html
 <div class="image-container">
            <a href="/"><img class="slider_item active"src="image01.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image02.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image03.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image04.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image05.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image06.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image07.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image08.png" width="84" height="115" />
            <img class="slider_item" src="image09.png" width="84" height="115" /></a>
           </div><!-- end image-container-->
```

Comment: What is the link to the jQuery image slider plugin which you are using? Any JSFiddle ?

Comment: there is no plugin for this, this is strictly jQuery, HTML, CSS only.